# What is flatMapPublisher in RxJava2?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2

What is the purpose of `flatMapPublisher` ?

```
return factory.retrieveDiskDataStore().isCached()
                .flatMapPublisher {
                    factory.retrieveDataStore(it).getData(token)
                }
                .flatMap {
                    Flowable.just(if (it is PickupListDataModel) mapper.mapFromData(it) else null)
                }
                .flatMap {
                    saveData(it).toSingle { it }.toFlowable()
                }
```

In this code, `factory.retrieveDiskDataStore().isCached()` checks whether the information is stored in database or not.
If not, then following code executes

```
.flatMapPublisher {
                    factory.retrieveDataStore(it).getData(token)
                }
```

Answer (score 3):

From the [JavaDocs](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Single.html#flatMapPublisher-io.reactivex.functions.Function-):

> Returns a `Flowable` that emits items based on applying a specified function to the item emitted by the source `Single`, where that function returns a `Publisher`.

[image: flatMapPublisher]

In other terms, a `Single` will succeed with a value which you'd like to turn into a sequence of values generated by a `Publisher` (i.e., some `Flowable`, `Flux` or other standard Reactive Streams source) and have the items of that.